# TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'training'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, object-detection, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am checking an object detection collaboratory notebook and it's supposed to work properly.
when i run its code to train the model it gives me it's error:

```
!keras_retinanet/bin/train.py \
```

--freeze-backbone 
--random-transform 
--weights {PRETRAINED_MODEL} 
--batch-size 8 
--steps 500 
--epochs 10 
csv annotations.csv classes.csv
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'training'

the model does not train and i couldn't figure out the exact problem

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add the code you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading to `keras==2.3.1` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: how do you downgrade to keras==2.3.1 ?

Comment: pip3 install keras==2.3.1. it should automatically uninstall previous version.

Comment: how can i downgrade to keras==2.3.1 on google collaboratory notebook?

Comment: @OubaidGharbi `! pip install keras==2.3.1`

Comment: But after downgrading to keras 2.3.1, I get this error with tf 2.3 


(`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'`)

Comment: @dracarys3 in my case I am running imageai and after i downgraded I got module error `tensorflow.image.resize_images`, I have resolved as follows `import tensorflow` and `tensorflow.image.resize_images = tensorflow.image.resize`